# How do I find all the polygons of a GeoDataframe that contain any point of another GeoDataframe in GeoPandas?

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have a GeoDataframe of about 3200 polygons, and another GeoDataframe of about 26,000 points. I want to get a third GeoDataframe of only the polygons that contain at least one point. This seems like it should be a simple `sjoin`, but `geopandas.sjoin(polygons, points, predicate='contains')` returns a GeoDataframe with more polygons than I started with (and very near the number of input points). Examining this GeoDataframe shows that there seem to be some duplicate polygons, perhaps explaining why I have more polygons than I expected. How do I find only the polygons that contain any point without duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

The *how* argument in the `sjoin` method seems to give the solution to this problem. It allows you to choose on which geodaframe you apply it. Here we want to have only the polygons so we use the indexes of the polygons geodaframe: `geopandas.sjoin(polygons, points, how='left', op='contains')`. This link in the doc provides more specific information:  https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/mergingdata.html#binary-predicate-joins

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to also seems to end up with more polys than expected (around 29k), including polys that don't contain any of the points.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, although I feel like it's not the best solution. My polygons have a unique ID column on which I was able to remove duplicates:

`geopandas.sjoin(polygons, points, predicate='contains').drop_duplicates(subset=['UNIQUE_ID'], keep='first')`

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with the following method :

```
def point_in_geom(geom, pts):
    """
    Test if at least one point in pts is within geom

    Args:
        geom: GeoDataframe geometry
        pts: GeoDataFrame containing all points

    Returns:
        True if one of the points is within the geometry or else False

    """
    for p in range(len(pts.index)):
        if pts.iloc[p].geometry.within(geom):
            return True
    return False
```

Create a column 'keep' which is True if the polygon contains at least one point or False if not.

```
def get_poly(all_poly, pts):
    """
    Get all polygons from all_poly containing at least one point from pts
    
    Args:
        all_poly: GeoDataFrame of Polygons
        pts: GeoDataFrame of Points

    Returns:
        GeoDataFrame including all Polygons that contain at least one Point

    """
    inter_poly = all_poly.copy(deep=True)
    inter_poly['keep'] = inter_poly.geometry.apply(lambda df: point_in_geom(df, pts))
    return inter_poly[inter_poly['keep']].drop(columns=['keep'])
```

You call get_poly on your GeoDataFrame of polygons, and points and the resulting GeoDataframe includes all polygons that contain at least one point. We drop the 'keep' column to get the exact same GeoDataFrame structure as the input.